# Location of Fuse and MOV

Tags: voltage, current, ac, fuses, mov

I have an AC module where the input is AC mains.

I am also using 2 AC-DC modules. [AC-DC module 1 5V output](https://www.mornsun-power.com/html/pdf/LS01-K3B05SS.html) & [AC-DC module 2 12V output](https://www.mornsun-power.com/html/pdf/LD05-23B12R2.html)

Both these AC-DC modules requires fuses. I also want to place an MOV.

Can you tell which is the right placement of the fuse and the MOV?

Is the below illustration correct, or is some modification required?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me.

Local fuses can be useful as they bring local protection i.e. without affecting the operation of the rest of the system.

Placing the main fuse right before the MOV protects the MOV as well so it doesn't "explode" during a fault (e.g. overvoltage) condition. Also, replacing it can be pain in the @$$ but it's easy to replace a fuse.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, you suggest 3 different fuses as suggested in my illustration at those same locations, is it?

Comment: @Freshman I can't say if I recommend or not. These configurations depend on the application requirements. A local protection (like shown in your illustration) is good where an individual module's failure is not required to stop the rest of the system. However, if a local failure **should** stop the rest of the system then a main fuse/breaker is sufficient. But this brings a problem: If the main fuse had to be chosen for a really high current then it won't blow in case of a relatively small, local problem which can cause larger problems without blowing fuse. So, local fuses can be beneficial.